# Ubuntu one password forgotten

Tags: ubuntu-one

I was trying to activate Ubuntu-one on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. After all entries were completed the system replied that e-mail has already been used. I remembered that some years back I tried Ubuntu on my system and may have created a Ubuntu-One account. I don't have password which i used at that time.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link: https://login.ubuntu.com/+forgot_password

Enter your Email address on the box. (The Email address you used to register on Ubuntu One.) They will send you an Email.

Either: 1) Ignore the Second step of the above page. Simply, open the link on the Email, and choose a new password. 2) If you had problem with openning the link, copy/paste the Code they send you on the Email, in the second step of the above page.

More information can be found on [FAQ](https://login.ubuntu.com/+faq) page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still have access to that email address,
https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-recover-or-change-my-password/

Comment: The link no longer works.